# Passing Visibility enum value as ConverterParameter

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to know how to pass System.Windows.Visibility Enum as parameter of a converter:

```
<Bdl:BdlRoundButton Name="BtAddUser" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Color="Orange" Image="Create" Command="{StaticResource GetSequence}" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringNotNullToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
```

Comment: try with `{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}`

Answer (score 0):

As @dkozl already mentioned, you can use the [x:Static Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension):

> References any static by-value code entity that is defined in a Common Language Specification (CLS)–compliant way. The static property that is referenced can be used to provide the value of a property in XAML.

So your code should look like this:

```
<Bdl:BdlRoundButton Name="BtAddUser" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Color="Orange" 
                    Image="Create" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    Command="{StaticResource GetSequence}" 
                    Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringNotNullToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
```